# how to pass a string into a nested function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out why I cant pass a string into a function that contains another function. I get `undefined` when I alert.

```
$.fn.downCount = function (current_time) {
    function countdown(current_time) {
        alert(current_time)
    }
})

var current_time = "01:00";
downCount(current_time);
```

Comment: But that code doesn't alert anything. Anyways, remove `current_time` as an argument of `countdown` if you want to use the `current_time` from `downCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually call the inner function.  Call the function and pass in the `current_time`.

```js
$.fn.downCount = function (current_time) {
    function countdown() {
        alert(current_time)
    }
    countdown();
}


var current_time = "01:00";
$.fn.downCount(current_time);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
```

Also, as Andrew mentioned, you don't need to pass in the `current_time` into the `countdown` function.  It can be simplified to:

```
$.fn.downCount = function (current_time) {
    function countdown() {
        alert(current_time)
    }
    countdown();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  I'd also like to add that in OP's original code there's an unnecessary ")" after the closing curly brace on initial plugin definition.  Looks like you caught that as well. Cheers.